# Python: map four arrays

Tags: python

What I want to do is somehow map two 2D arrays.
I have two pairs of corresponding arrays:

```
x1=[1,2,3,4,5]
y1=[7,9,10,17,4]

x2=[3,4,5,6,7]
y2=[5,4,1,13,12]
```

What I would like my program to do is:

Step 1. compare x1 with x2 and find matching elements

```
[3,4,5]
```

Step 2. For those matching elements perform a substraction of matching y-elements:

`[y1(x)-y2(x)]=[y1(3)-y2(3), y1(4)-y2(4), y1(5)-y2(5)]`

which is the same as:
`[10-5, 17-4, 4-1]=[5,13,3]`

Step 3. Return another two arrays, that has unused elements from x1, y1, x2, y2 and those after substraction. Expected result:

`x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [7,9,5,13,3,13,12]`

Is there an easy way to do something like that, maybe using map()? Those are all separate arrays.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @azro I have no idea how to start, due to the fact there are four arrays. I'm trying to zip() them both into dictionaries and maybe map them together then? Not sure if it's gonna work, maybe there's a better idea to do that.

Comment: What the values of x and y for the 3rd point ? do the steps so we understand

Comment: @azro actually the steps are done above. Not sure how would I describe them better than this.

Comment: The step to get the array x and y of the end, there is no step explained, just a sentence, bu I think i get it

Comment: when you say `y2(5)`  you mean, find the index of 5 in x2 then find the value in y2 ? That's not really obvious

Comment: We use 3,4,5 from both x1 and x2, so why keep it in x ? I make a pause for here, and leave my answer like , until maybe you make it more clear. **and i repeat**, i asked details for the 3rd points, not the second

Comment: Don't use corresponding arrays in the first place; use dicts. Also: what is the *meaning* of this computation? In particular, I suspect that the unmatched values from `y` actually ought to be negated. Can you convince me otherwise? What are you planning to *do with* these results?

Answer (score 1):

1. To get common elements between 2 lists, use `set` and operator `&`

   ```
   x_common_vals = set(x1) & set(x2)
   print(x_common_vals) #{3, 4, 5}
   ```
2. For the substraction operation, for each value you need to get its index in `x1` and `x2` and get the value at that index in `y1` and `y2`, like `y1[x1.index(value)]`

   ```
   y_sub = list(map(lambda v: y1[x1.index(v)] - y2[x2.index(v)], x_common_vals))
   print(y_sub)  # [5, 13, 3]
   ```
3. WorkInProgress

Answer (score 1):

```
print( [ y1[x1.index(elt)]-y2[x2.index(elt)] for elt in x1 if elt in x2 ] )
```

[image]

To get all keys, but not very efficient

```
[ y1[x1.index(elt)]-y2[x2.index(elt)] if elt in x2 else y1[x1.index(elt)] for elt in x1 ]+[ y2[x2.index(elt)] for elt in x2 if elt not in x1 ]
```

[image]
Another method for both parts, using dictionaries to be more efficient

```
d1 = {x:y for x,y in zip(x1,y1)}
d2 = {x:y for x,y in zip(x2,y2)}
d = d2.copy()
d = { k:(d1[k]-v if k in d1 else v) for k,v in d.items() }
res = d1.copy()
res.update(d)
X, Y = list(res.keys()), list(res.values())
print(X, Y, sep="\n")
```

[image]

If you have huge date, then use pandas dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"k":x1, "v1":y1}).set_index("k")
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"k":x2, "v2":y2}).set_index("k")

def f(row):
    a, b = row[0], row[1]
    if a and b:
        return a - b
    elif a:
        return a
    else:
        return b

df = df1.join(other=df2, how="outer").fillna('')
df = pd.DataFrame({"v":df.apply(f, axis=1)} )
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Please when you want to show the result of you code, 1.an image is the not the best, and also your captures show also the code (so twice), and the result can be pasted as code-text below the code, you won't be more trusted  if you show picture ;)